# How to get values out of a nested map

Tags: maps, elixir

Looking for best way to get the values of "lat" and "lon" out of this:

```
{:ok,
%Geocoder.Coords{
  bounds: %Geocoder.Bounds{
  bottom: 43.1949619,
  left: -86.2468396,
  right: -86.24483359999999,
  top: 43.19497399999999
},
 lat: 43.19497399999999,
 location: %Geocoder.Location{
 city: "Muskegon Heights",
 country: "United States",
 country_code: "US",
 formatted_address: "Amsterdam, Muskegon Heights, MI 49444, USA",
 postal_code: "49444",
 state: "Michigan",
 street: "Amsterdam",
 street_number: nil
},
lon: -86.24586719999999
}}
```

Thanks for advice.

Comment: _Sidenote:_ https://github.com/amotion-city/lib_lat_lon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Again for sake of completeness, it seems as if you could use Map.get/3 here too.

```rb
defmodule Geocoder.Bounds do
  defstruct [:bottom, :left, :right, :top]
end

defmodule Geocoder.Location do
  defstruct [
    :city,
    :country,
    :country_code,
    :formatted_address,
    :postal_code,
    :state,
    :street,
    :street_number
  ]
end

defmodule Geocoder.Coords do
  defstruct [:bounds, :lat, :location, :lon]
end

defmodule Test do
  alias Geocoder.{Bounds, Location, Coords}

  def new() do
    b = %Bounds{bottom: 43.19, left: -86, right: -86, top: 43}

    l = %Location{
      city: "abc",
      country: "usa",
      country_code: "usa",
      formatted_address: "",
      postal_code: "49444",
      state: "Michigan",
      street: "Amsterdam",
      street_number: nil
    }

    {:ok, %Coords{bounds: b, lat: 43.1, location: l, lon: -86.2}}
  end

  def get_lat() do
    g = new()
    elem(g, 1) |> Map.get(:lat)
  end

  def get_lon() do
    g = new()
    elem(g, 1) |> Map.get(:lon)
  end
end
```

Although I think @dogbert's approach is better, I offer this again just to offer a potential alternative.

BTW, I know I didn't use all the same values as your sample code but I was getting tired of copy/pasting the code from your example. And the differences in that shouldn't be salient anyway.

Answer (score 4):

You can use pattern matching like this:

```
# assuming the value in your question is stored in `value`
{:ok, %{lat: lat, lon: lon}} = value
IO.inspect lat
IO.inspect lon
```

You can also extract the whole value and access `lat` and `lon` using a dot:

```
{:ok, coords} = value
IO.inspect coords.lat
IO.inspect coords.lon
```

Comment: ShorterMaps provides a convenient shorthand for the first approach; `{:ok, ~M{lat, lon}} = value`

Comment: For a minute there I thought I'd missed a new sigil in the language :)

Answer (score 0):

Also for completeness and as the question mentions nested maps I would like to recommend the good old `Kernel` module.
It provides us with mighty tools such as [`Kernel.get_in/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#get_in/2). It is a bit overkill for your question, but say you would like to get the city nested within `:location`:

```
elem(geo_data, 1) |> get_in([:location, :city])
```

**Beware this only works on Maps and structs that implement the Access behaviour.**